# Why is the inner loop executing (n/2) times instead of (n) times

Tags: java, big-o

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)   {
 for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[i] == array[j]) return true;
    }
}
```

Edit: Forgot to add the outer loop. i is initialized to zero.

Why is this code executing (n/2) times instead of (n) times?

Comment: What is the variable `i` initialized to?

Comment: You need to provide more code.

Comment: This is nested inside another loop, right?  Perhaps you should show all of it.

Comment: Please see edit: I added the outer loop. However I just only need to know the explanation of the running time of the "inner loop".

Comment: Because `j` starts at `i + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop executes n/2 times on the average:

- On the first iteration this executes up to n-1 times, because j starts at 1
- On the second iteration this executes up to n-2 times, because j starts at 2
- On the third iteration this executes up to n-3 times, because j starts at 3
- ...
- On the last iteration this executes zero times, because i+1 is equal to the length of the array.

If you add the first line to the last, the second to the second from the back, the third to the third from the back and so on, each pair would yield n-1; there would be n/2 such pairs for even values of n, so an average number of times the loop executes over n is n/2.

Comment: On a side note , is the "if statement" running at O(1)? Is analyzing the if statement important in the "algorithm analysis"?

Comment: @Nicholas Absolutely, for reference and value comparisons it does.